# How to make a div not scroll off the page using jquery

Tags: jquery, scroll

Basically I have a structure which is something like this:

```
<body>
   <div> main content </div>
   <div> toolbar </div>
   <div> results </div>
```

When scrolling down, I want the "main content" to disappear off the screen. The 'toolbar' to stay flush with the top of the page, and the 'results' to scroll, disappearing into the 'toolbar' as they scroll.

EDIT: the toolbar starts off in the middle of the screen. I want it to scroll to the top, but then no further, but the rest of the page (below) keeps scrolling.

I found this tutorial http://www.wduffy.co.uk/blog/keep-element-in-view-while-scrolling-using-jquery/

But this is slightly different. In the example above, although the toolbar stays near the top, it prevents the results from being scrolled.

Comment: It sounds like a simple, `style="position: fixed;"` could solve your needs.

Comment: I pared back my initial very long question too, aggressively, please see the edit.

Comment: Fixed position does indeed do the nicest looking scrolling. You could do some jQuery to check if the div fits in the screen, because else it wouldn't be fully accessible. You could do some switching between fixed and absolute as well at the moment your div is at some max position.

Comment: style="position: fixed;" firstly causes the results to overlap with the toolbar and secondly, as I scroll down, the toolbar div, slowly moves downwards very slowly .. I am using Firefox 3.6

Answer (score 1):

I would have position:fixed; for the toolbar. That way it will stay fixed in the view.

```
<body>
   <div> main content </div>
   <div style="position:fixed;"> toolbar </div>
   <div> results </div>
```

Comment: display: absolute doesn't exist... With `position: fixed;` you can then assign the position using top,left,right,bottom properties.

Comment: Haha, woops.. I was way over my head there. Thanks :o) I for some reason mixed display with position.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using ASP.NET AJAX?  If so you can use something like the Always visible control:

http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/HOW%20TO%20Use%20the%20AlwaysVisible%20Control.ashx

If not I believe there are some jQuery remakes of it, I believe this one might work as well:

http://www.west-wind.com/WebLog/posts/388213.aspx

Comment: Unfortunately not, using Java/Servlets/JSPs etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".myDivClass").css("overflow", "hidden");
```